# Passing NavigationService to Usercontrol windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to pass navigationservice to my user control.
At my application side

```
<myControl:Test  NavigationService="{Binding NavigationService}"/>/>
```

at my Usercontrol CS side

```
 public NavigationService NavigationService { get; set; }
```

but it dosent seems to work,application crashes as soon as it loads.

Comment: In addition to the answer. If you call the `NavigationService.Navigate` method in the userControl, that will cause a crash. That's relative to page navigation queue. If you press the "back" button, the app should return to previous page - the one, you've navigated from. So you can't navigate from userControl. To simplify, the call NavigationService.Navigate() is equal to phoneApplicationPage.NavigationService.Navigate() call, where phoneApplicationPage is a page, from where you're navigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's really harsh... Alright, You haven't mentioned this, but I suppose, that you try to solve the problem of navigating from UserControl to other page/uc(is it true?).

A couple of edits:

1. First, You don't need an *object of class* to use a
       NavigationSevice.
2. Second, the NavigationService is most usually used with *pages*.

If you really *do* want to use it with UserControl, you should transfer an instance of page to control. But, in my experience, usually, this is not required. I would rather recommend to do in this way:

In your UserControl you will most definitely have the controls with tap/click events. No need to describe their logic in user control class. When you add the user control to page, you should declare it there. Like:

```
someUserControl.buttonNavigate.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(buttonNavigate_Click);
```

And then you can use navigation service.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(...));
```

That's the easiest solution. Hope it helps.

There are another ones, but I hope this one will solve the problem.

Comment: i dont want to give the user control to navigate to the next page.Actually i want to show a small image bar on click of tht i want to open a larger Fullscreen image from another source(somewht like a Ad). I am confused about how to go about with it as I can't load another view

Comment: Can you define, what you need to do more precisely? First, you told about **User Control** and **NavigationService**. Now, you tell about images, however I can't see how this connects with the userControl and NavigationService at all. Sorry, but I don't understand this. Please edit your question.